# Typescript: Exclude<T, K> doesn't exclude my type

Tags: typescript, generics

I built a function called `compact`, what this function do is to remove all falsy values in an array.

This is the `javascript` implementation of `compact`:

```
function compact(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}

const MyData = [0, 1, null, 2, undefined, ''];

console.log(compact(MyData))
// => [1, 2]
```

This is the `Typescript` **typing part** of `compact`:

```js
type Falsy = false | null | 0 | '' | undefined;

type Compact<T extends any[]> = Exclude<T[number], Falsy>;

// some correct test
type MyData = [0, 1, null, 2, undefined, ''];

type MyDataWithoutFalsy = Compact<MyData>
// => type MyDataWithoutFalsy = 1 | 2
```

[image]

Now, here comes the **weird part**, when I hook it up with `compact` code, it's not actually working:

```js
function compact<T extends any[]>(arr: T): Compact<T> {
  return arr.filter(Boolean) as Compact<T>;
}

let MyDataWithoutFalsy = compact([0, 1, null, 2, undefined, '']);
// => let MyDataWithoutFalsy: string | number, but it should be `number` only, because empty string should be excluded.
```

It should be `number` only, because empty string should be excluded.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with `Exclude`, the problem is that for `""` (and not just for this string literal, for any string literal) typescript will not usually keep the string literal type but it will rather widen it to `string` unless we give it a reason to preserve the literal type.

To hint to the compiler you want a literal type the literal must be assigned to a generic type parameter that is constrained to a literal base type:

```
function compact<V extends (string | undefined | boolean | object | number | null), T extends V[]>(arr: T & V[]): Compact<T> {
    return arr.filter(Boolean) as Compact<T>;
}

let MyDataWithoutFalsy = compact([0, 1, null, 2, undefined, '']); // number


type Falsy = false | null | 0 | '' | undefined;

type Compact<T extends any[]> = Exclude<T[number], Falsy>;
```

Note that this does mean that `compact` will not really be usable unless you construct the array in such a way as to preserve literal types (such as `''`).

```
function compact<V extends (string | undefined | boolean | object | number | null), T extends V[]>(arr: T & V[]): Compact<T> {
    return arr.filter(Boolean) as Compact<T>;
}
function literalArray<V extends (string | undefined | boolean | object | number | null)>(arr: V[]): V[] {
    return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
let arr = literalArray([0, 1, null, 2, undefined, ''])
let MyDataWithoutFalsy = compact(arr); // 1| 2 ... beacuse resons
```